# How to set desired capabilities for launching ios app on real device with appium ( c#)

Tags: ios, appium

Hi I am automating the native ios application on ios . I already automated android native app but for launching the appium server on mac from c# code running on windows I need to know how to setup the Desired capabilities for ios platform.

Answer (score 2):

Please find the below peace of code for c# language:

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
 TestCapabilities testCapabilities = new TestCapabilities();

  testCapabilities.App = "";
  testCapabilities.AutoWebView = true;
  testCapabilities.AutomationName = "";
  testCapabilities.BrowserName = String.Empty; // Leave empty otherwise you test on browsers
  testCapabilities.DeviceName = "Needed if testing on IOS on a specific device. This will be the UDID";
  testCapabilities.Platform = TestCapabilities.DevicePlatform.IOS; // Or Android
  testCapabilities.PlatformVersion = String.Empty; // Not really needed

  testCapabilities.AssignAppiumCapabilities(ref capabilities);
  driver = new AppiumDriver(testServerAddress, capabilities, INIT_TIMEOUT_SEC);
  driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(IMPLICIT_TIMEOUT_SEC);
```

Answer (score 0):

To run Appium test on iOS simulator/real device, Mac hardware is needed and to run test on real device, team id from apple developer account is also needed. More details [here](https://appium.io/docs/en/drivers/ios-xcuitest-real-devices/).

Connect the iPhone to MacOS via cable or connect both iPhone and Mac computer to same wireless network (WiFi).

C# code for initialising appium iOS driver to run test on real device:

```
//Initialise driver options
AppiumOptions capabilities = new AppiumOptions();

//Declare capabilities
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformName, "iOS");
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PlatformVersion, "13.2"); //put real device iOS version
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DeviceName, "iPhone X"; //put real device name
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AutomationName, "XCUITest");

if (appInstalled)
{
    //if app is installed and don't want to re-install, use below capability
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.BundleId, "<app-bundle-id>");
}

else
{
    //(re)installs app
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.AppName, "<name-of-test-app>");
    capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.App, "<absolute-path-to-test-app.app>");
}

capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability(MobileCapabilityType.Udid, "<real-device-Udid>");
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("xcodeOrgId", "<team-id>");
capabilities.AddAdditionalCapability("xcodeSigningId","iPhone Developer");

//Initialise iOS driver
var driver = new IOSDriver<IMobileElement<AppiumWebElement>>(capabilities);
```